# Make index.php catch all URLs while inside a directory?

Tags: .htaccess

So I have the following `.htaccess` file contents from my other project which is accessed at `http://www.example.com/`.

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Now the above works quite fine but now I have a new problem. I want to use the same concept (redirecting all links to index.php) but this time, it needs to be inside a directory. (e.g. `http://www.myothersite.com/thisfolder/`)

So I tried creating a `.htaccess` file inside `http://www.myothersite.com/thisfolder/`. Question is, how do I modify the above code so that it points all links to `index.php` inside `thisfolder`?

Just for reference see below:

```
myothersite.com
 '-> thisfolder
      '-> .htaccess
      '-> index.php
```

I need to place the `.htaccess` file inside `thisfolder` since I don't want it messing with the other projects I have on other folders. I want to keep all the action specifically inside `http://www.myothersite.com/thisfolder/`.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

`RewriteRule . /thisfolder/index.php [L,NC,QSA]`